# Swipe to delete

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've looked and i can't seem to find any where on stack overflow some one that has had the same problem as me. So I use the following code:

```
  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete); 
}
```

and when i swipe the delete button appears, but when pressed it doesn't do anything, what have i forgotten to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to actually delete your data after the `if` statement. Currently, your `if` statement does nothing at all, because it just has a semi-colon after it.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //Code to delete data goes here.
        //This could include removing an object from an array, deleting it from core data,
        //and removing the selected row.
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I could have worked this out, but more often than not, it's quite simply quicker to look here first.  Great, simple answer, and it works brilliantly.